# IBus input method is working in GTK apps only on Debian testing (bookworm)

Tags: debian, ibus

I try to get IBus input methods working on my Debian testing (bookworm) under Gnome 43. For example `pinyin`

I installed it with

```
sudo apt install ibus-pinyin
```

When I switch to Chinese now the Chinese input works only in GTK apps but not for example in `Firefox` or in `Electron` born apps like `Atom` or `Signal`.

What could be the cause of this problem and how to fix it? Is this a Debian bug or a specific problem of my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this issue by editing the file  `/etc/environment`

I added the following lines:

```
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
```

So the files' content is the following:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
# Custom: Add Searchable command palette to any GTK3 Application.
GTK3_MODULES=$GTK3_MODULES:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplotinus/libplotinus.so
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
```